# Axios response return nested objects not array , how to use FlatList to get names and values

Tags: react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

i use axios to fetch data from currencyfreaks.com
the data received is just nested objects , i need to use FlatList to retrieve names of all currency and values too in **rates object**

**part of received data**

```
 LOG  {"date":"2023-10-09 00:00:00+00","base":"USD","rates":{"AGLD":"1.7102787754403967","FJD":"2.27174500081435","MXN":"18.24318410775992","LVL":"0.664977","SCR":"12.915987254727746","CDF":"2502.0839339160466","BBD":"2.0","HNL":"24.640277645718122","UGX":"3737.2486566078455","GLM":"5.295207836907599","NEAR":"0.9136592051164915","AIOZ":"81.30081300813008","AUDIO":"6.879944960440317","HNT":"0.6918021445866482","FARM":"0.0434782608695652","SDG":"601.5","IQD":"1307.684997195403","GMD":"65.49855","RBN":"5.795589556347619","ZRX":"4.670311066068556","BCH":"0.0043832734285965","MYR":"4.713624996685141","FKP":"0.8183326632114318","XOF":"621.0525189758589","GMT":"6.5359477124183005","SEI":"8.64304235090752","SEK":"10.976868665200229","GNF":"8594.6265465","MZN":"63.86497632384554","QAR":"3.6364245","IRR":"42243.74907514374","GNO":"0.0103707544723879","GNT":"5.322957272306343","FLR":"96.01536245799328","XPD":"0.0008653484923242","THB":"36.9425","XPF":"112.918458","ABT":"13.8217000691085","BDT":"110.0115685","T":"50.365147318055904","LYD":"4.884603641726681","KWD":"0.309145","DIA":"4.226453371653177","XPT":"0.00114397","ISK":"137.06","JUP":"1159.7775456615134","ACH":"70.49948887870563","MINA":"2.635046113306983","VTHO":"859.106529209622","PAB":"1.0","ACS":"554.3083617416369","SGD":"1.3663749996218686","BLUR":"5.803830528148578","REN":"21.85792349726776","ELA":"0.7270083605961469","REP":"1.7738081183344143","ADA":"3.8978756577665172","REQ":"15.32567049808429","STORJ":"2.126980750824205","CHF":"0.9089786662923746","HRK":"7.130389","RARI":"1.1049723756906078","DJF":"177.5590275","RARE":"16.863406408094434","PAX":"1.0019538099293623","VND":"24386.05973130686","CHZ":"16.666666666666668","KYD":"0.8314703459071806","XRP":"1.9310611180843873","JASMY":"298.9536621823617","SHP":"0.8183003016601705","INDEX":"1.1049723756906078","TJS":"10.96203579223938","AED":"3.6730566666666666","FIDA":"6.090133982947624","SAND":"3.343922420999833","DKK":"7.056251","WCFG":"2.9368575624082234","ZWD":"377.4","OCEAN":"3.3250207813798838","BGN":"1.8481835482871731","UMA":"0.7374631268436578","FOX":"50.505050505050505","ZWL":"5872.61","HTG":"134.07398286660617","RGT":"1.2359734153663686","BHD":"0.376263","ENJ":"4.395604395604396","COVAL":"150.03750937734435","CGLD":"2.296211251435132","KZT":"476.8355568192539","YFII":"0.0017492598860505","DIMO":"11.268240464251507","GRT":"11.743981209630064",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic keys to access the values.

*First Access rates*

```
const rates = LOG["rates"]
/// output : {'AGLD': 1.25645, "FRP": 1.0215, ...}
```

At this point you have a few options.

*Access it dynamically:*

```
const AGLD = rates[`AGLD`]
```

or create an array of the values

```
const rateObjectEntries= Object.entries(rates)
/// output: [['AGLD',1.25645], ['FRP',1.0215], ...]
 
const toArr = rateObjectEntries.map((v)=>{

/// dynamically return new object for each element in the array

  return {[`${v[0]}`]: v[1]} /// output: [{'AGLD':1.25645},{'FRP',1.0215},..]

-or-

  return { currency: v[0], rate: v[1] } // output: [{currency:'AGLD', rate: 
    1.25645},..]

})
```

Then you can map through the rates in either of the two formats from above.